# How to refer an Kotlin object type in Java?

Tags: java, kotlin

I have the Kotlin object as below:

```
object TestObject {
    val name: String = "Hi"
}
```

How would I refer to `TestObject` in Java? The code below doesn't understand `TestObject.name`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(TestObject.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to create an instance of the `TestObject` (i.e. `new TestObject().name`) - unless the property `name` is `public static`, then you can make references to `TestObject.name`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two things going on here, both related to how Kotlin/JVM generates Java bytecode.  (These are implementation details that aren't visible from other Kotlin code, but become apparent when you access it from Java.)

- A singleton object gets translated to a class, and its single instance gets stored in a field of that object called `INSTANCE`.
- A Kotlin property consists of accessor methods (getter and, if writable, setter), and (if needed) a backing field.  These get translated to a private field, and methods with the relevant visibility named in the conventional way (`getField()` and `setField()`, or `isField()` and `setField()` if the property's called `isField`).

Putting that together, you can refer to the property in the question from Java code as:

```
TestObject.INSTANCE.getName()
```

(Full details on how to access Kotlin from Java are [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html).)

Comment: @ochi: Yes, Kotlin generates the accessor(s) and backing field as needed.  (At least, Kotlin/JVM does; I don't know about the other platforms.)  Strictly, the property _is_ the getter (and, if present, setter) — most properties also have a backing field, but you don't have to have one if you override the accessor(s).  (Which is how extension properties work.)  Of course, the Kotlin syntax makes it look like you're accessing a field directly, but you're not; Java doesn't know about this, so it's more obvious there.

Comment: `TestObject.INSTANCE` is what I am looking for. Thanks a lot!